apt upgrade on wsl kali linux taking forever
I've just installed kali linux on a windows 11 laptop using the wsl --install -d kali-linux command on powershell. Everything was fine, Running apt update works normally, but when I run apt upgrade it gets stuck here:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-utils bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs coreutils curl e2fsprogs fdisk git iproute2 kmod libapt-pkg-perl libbpf1
  libcryptsetup12 libfido2-1 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkmod2 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.5-0 liblocale-gettext-perl
  libncursesw6 libnsl2 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-systemd libpython3.11-minimal libpython3.11-stdlib librtmp1
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsystemd-shared libsystemd0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtinfo6
  openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl parted perl perl-base python3-apt python3.11 python3.11-minimal sudo
  systemd tcpdump tmux tnftp wget zsh
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files bash bsdutils ca-certificates cron cron-daemon-common dash dbus dbus-bin dbus-daemon dbus-user-session debianutils
  distro-info-data dmsetup dpkg gcc-14-base gpgv gzip ifupdown kali-defaults kali-linux-core kali-linux-wsl kali-system-cli
  kali-system-core less libacl1 libapparmor1 libblkid1 libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-l10n libc6 libcap-ng0 libcom-err2
  libdbus-1-3 libdebconfclient0 libdevmapper1.02.1 libedit2 libexpat1 libfdisk1 libffi8 libfstrm0 libgcc-s1 libgcrypt20
  libgpg-error0 libgpm2 libldap-common liblz4-1 liblzma5 libmnl0 libmount1 libnftables1 libnftnl11 libnghttp2-14 libp11-kit0
  libpam-runtime libpam0g libprotobuf-c1 libpython3-stdlib libselinux1 libsemanage2 libsepol2 libslang2 libsmartcols1 libsodium23
  libsqlite3-0 libss2 libstdc++6 libtirpc-common libudev1 libunistring5 liburing2 libutempter0 libuuid1 libwrap0 libx11-6 libxau6
  libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxml2 libxmuu1 locales-all logsave mount nano ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term net-tools
  netcat-traditional nftables perl-modules-5.38 plocate python-apt-common python3 python3-minimal readline-common systemd-dev
  systemd-sysv sysvinit-utils tasksel tasksel-data tzdata tzdata-legacy udev util-linux vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny whois
  zlib1g
113 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 207 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libc-l10n all 2.38-10 [723 kB]
Get:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 locales-all amd64 2.38-10 [10.7 MB]
Get:24 http://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 sysvinit-utils amd64 3.09-1 [32.3 kB]
Get:1 http://mirror.leitecastro.com/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 base-files amd64 1:2024.2.0 [75.4 kB]
Get:26 http://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpam0g amd64 1.5.3-7 [67.7 kB]
Get:34 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdbus-1-3 amd64 1.14.10-4+b1 [203 kB]
Get:29 http://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 255.5-1 [51.2 kB]
Get:48 http://mirror.leitecastro.com/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gpgv amd64 2.2.40-3 [649 kB]
Get:56 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsemanage2 amd64 3.5-1+b3 [90.3 kB]
Get:72 http://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libbsd0 amd64 0.12.2-1 [131 kB]
Get:99 http://mirror.leitecastro.com/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libss2 amd64 1.47.1-1 [27.6 kB]
Get:91 http://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libcom-err2 amd64 1.47.1-1 [22.9 kB]
Get:100 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libtirpc-common all 1.3.4+ds-1.3 [10.9 kB]
Get:104 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxau6 amd64 1:1.0.9-1+b1 [18.1 kB]
Get:106 http://archive-4.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxcb1 amd64 1.17.0-2 [144 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.38-10 [2,768 kB]
Get:5 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libc-bin amd64 2.38-10 [611 kB]
Get:6 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gcc-14-base amd64 14-20240330-1 [43.2 kB]
Get:7 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgcc-s1 amd64 14-20240330-1 [71.9 kB]
Get:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libstdc++6 amd64 14-20240330-1 [713 kB]
Get:9 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 debianutils amd64 5.17 [89.0 kB]
Get:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 bash amd64 5.2.21-2+b1 [1,493 kB]
Get:11 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.40-8 [101 kB]
Get:12 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dash amd64 0.5.12-8 [93.3 kB]
Get:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dpkg amd64 1.22.6+kali1 [1,512 kB]
Get:14 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gzip amd64 1.12-1.1 [133 kB]
Get:15 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ncurses-bin amd64 6.5-2 [433 kB]
Get:16 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.40-8 [164 kB]
Get:17 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libselinux1 amd64 3.5-2+b2 [74.9 kB]
Get:18 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.40-8 [195 kB]
Get:19 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.40-8 [135 kB]
Get:20 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.40-8 [32.6 kB]
Get:21 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.40-8 [1,206 kB]
Get:22 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ncurses-base all 6.5-2 [270 kB]
Get:23 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ncurses-term all 6.5-2 [513 kB]
Get:25 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 mount amd64 2.40-8 [147 kB]
Get:27 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpam-runtime all 1.5.3-7 [140 kB]
Get:28 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 cron amd64 3.0pl1-189 [86.0 kB]
Get:30 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dbus-user-session amd64 1.14.10-4+b1 [79.1 kB]
Get:31 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dbus-bin amd64 1.14.10-4+b1 [106 kB]
Get:32 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dbus amd64 1.14.10-4+b1 [98.6 kB]
Get:33 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dbus-daemon amd64 1.14.10-4+b1 [185 kB]
Get:35 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 3.0.13-2 [41.6 kB]
Get:36 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libcap-ng0 amd64 0.8.5-1 [17.1 kB]
Get:37 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.6.2-1 [103 kB]
Get:38 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 perl-modules-5.38 all 5.38.2-4 [2,907 kB]
Get:39 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-minimal amd64 3.11.8-1 [26.3 kB]
Get:40 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3 amd64 3.11.8-1 [27.4 kB]
Get:41 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpython3-stdlib amd64 3.11.8-1 [9,332 B]
Get:42 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tasksel-data all 3.75+kali1 [18.2 kB]
Get:43 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tasksel all 3.75+kali1 [47.4 kB]
Get:44 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libbz2-1.0 amd64 1.0.8-5.1 [38.0 kB]
Get:45 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgpg-error0 amd64 1.49-2 [79.9 kB]
Get:46 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgcrypt20 amd64 1.10.3-3 [708 kB]
Get:47 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 zlib1g amd64 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1 [87.6 kB]
Get:49 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libacl1 amd64 2.3.2-2 [32.4 kB]
Get:50 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdebconfclient0 amd64 0.271+b3 [10.2 kB]
Get:51 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libffi8 amd64 3.4.6-1 [23.6 kB]
Get:52 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liblz4-1 amd64 1.9.4-2 [61.4 kB]
Get:53 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liblzma5 amd64 5.6.1+really5.4.5-1 [240 kB]
Get:54 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libp11-kit0 amd64 0.25.3-5 [417 kB]
Get:55 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsepol2 amd64 3.5-2+b1 [278 kB]
Get:57 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 systemd-dev all 255.5-1 [60.5 kB]
Get:58 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-defaults all 2024.2.0 [466 kB]
Get:59 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 udev amd64 255.5-1 [1,796 kB]
Get:60 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 255.5-1 [126 kB]
Get:61 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libunistring5 amd64 1.2-1 [425 kB]
Get:62 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tzdata all 2024a-4 [255 kB]
Get:63 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tzdata-legacy all 2024a-4 [170 kB]
Get:64 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 cron-daemon-common all 3.0pl1-189 [16.8 kB]
Get:65 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ifupdown amd64 0.8.43 [61.1 kB]
Get:66 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 less amd64 643-1 [148 kB]
Get:67 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 nano amd64 8.0-1 [659 kB]
Get:68 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libmnl0 amd64 1.0.5-2+b1 [12.2 kB]
Get:69 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libnftnl11 amd64 1.2.6-2+b1 [63.4 kB]
Get:70 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 nftables amd64 1.0.9-2 [73.3 kB]
Get:71 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libnftables1 amd64 1.0.9-2 [315 kB]
Get:73 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20240517-1 [93.3 kB]
Get:74 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 readline-common all 8.2-4 [69.3 kB]
Get:75 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim amd64 2:9.1.0377-1 [1,614 kB]
Get:76 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-common all 2:9.1.0377-1 [410 kB]
Get:77 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:9.1.0377-1 [741 kB]
Get:78 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:9.1.0377-1 [7,133 kB]
Get:79 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgpm2 amd64 1.20.7-11 [14.0 kB]
Get:80 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsodium23 amd64 1.0.18-1+b1 [163 kB]
Get:81 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20240203 [158 kB]
Get:82 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 netcat-traditional amd64 1.10-48.1 [63.0 kB]
Get:83 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 distro-info-data all 0.62 [6,344 B]
Get:84 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdevmapper1.02.1 amd64 2:1.02.196-1+b1 [134 kB]
Get:85 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dmsetup amd64 2:1.02.196-1+b1 [82.6 kB]
Get:86 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-system-core amd64 2024.2.10 [13.2 kB]
Get:87 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-linux-core amd64 2024.2.10 [13.1 kB]
Get:88 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-system-cli amd64 2024.2.10 [13.1 kB]
Get:89 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 net-tools amd64 2.10-1.1 [243 kB]
Get:90 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-linux-wsl amd64 2024.2.10 [13.1 kB]
Get:92 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libfdisk1 amd64 2.40-8 [206 kB]
Get:93 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libfstrm0 amd64 0.6.1-1+b2 [21.8 kB]
Get:94 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.5.17+dfsg-1 [31.5 kB]
Get:95 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.61.0-1+b1 [75.6 kB]
Get:96 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libprotobuf-c1 amd64 1.4.1-1+b2 [27.4 kB]
Get:97 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libslang2 amd64 2.3.3-5 [551 kB]
Get:98 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.45.3-1 [896 kB]
Get:101 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liburing2 amd64 2.6-1 [23.9 kB]
Get:102 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libutempter0 amd64 1.2.1-3+b1 [9,256 B]
Get:103 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libwrap0 amd64 7.6.q-33 [55.1 kB]
Get:105 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxdmcp6 amd64 1:1.1.2-3+b1 [24.3 kB]
Get:107 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.8.7-1+b1 [799 kB]
Get:108 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxml2 amd64 2.9.14+dfsg-1.3+b3 [692 kB]
Get:109 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxmuu1 amd64 2:1.1.3-3+b2 [21.9 kB]
Get:110 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 logsave amd64 1.47.1-1 [22.7 kB]
Get:111 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 plocate amd64 1.1.22-3 [144 kB]
Get:112 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-apt-common all 2.9.0 [66.2 kB]
Get:113 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 whois amd64 5.5.23 [71.4 kB]
Fetched 49.0 MB in 35s (1,417 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 30058 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_1%3a2024.2.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-files (1:2024.2.0) over (1:2024.1.0) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/lib/systemd/system-preset': Directory not empty
Setting up base-files (1:2024.2.0) ...
(Reading database ... 30058 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-l10n_2.38-10_all.deb ...
Unpacking libc-l10n (2.38-10) over (2.37-12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../locales-all_2.38-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking locales-all (2.38-10) over (2.37-12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.38-10_amd64.deb ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.38-10) over (2.37-12) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.38-10) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Nothing to restart.

Progress: [  2%] [##.............................................................................................................]

I tried waiting, it took a whole day and it's still 2%. I tried configuring dpkg manually, and there's an error while processing libc6:amd64 and libc-bin. I know it's not a matter of time, I'm sure that there's an actual problem and it should be fixed. Don't you have any ideas?

It does look like there's a problem here, but may I ask why you want to install Kali? I mean, unless you are a professional penetration tester, there's not much point in using Kali instead of a normal operating system. I understand Windows also offers the choice of installing Ubuntu, is there any reason not to use that instead of Kali? Ubuntu can do anything that Kali can do (and much more; you just need to install a couple of packages) and would greatly simplify anything you would want to do. See should I use Kali?.

I already have ubuntu installed but I wanted to learn ethical hacking so I thought I need to install kali linux. So, you're telling me installing it is not necessary and ubuntu on its own is enough?

Oh yes, absolutely. Kali isn't magic, it is just a particularly hobbled and limited Linux which ships with a few tools by default, but all those tools are also installable
(warning: that's just the first random search result) on any other distribution. If you're learning then you don't want Kali. If you are working as a professional in the field, then it might be a good choice, but never to learn. Also see Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?.

Okay, thanks for your suggestions and helping me save a lot of time.

This is the second post I've come across in just the last couple of days showing a Kali upgrade stuck at 2%. Makes me wonder if there is an underlying issue

Try sudo pkill -9 telinit in another window

It works! the pkill -9 telinit command solved it! Thanks for your help man.

This is the fourth post I've come across in just the last few days showing a Kali upgrade stuck at 2%. Makes me wonder if there is an underlying issue.
I'm not terribly keen on posting this answer here as I have no way of validating the underlying reason for this solution. However, I've been told it works so here it is:
sudo pkill -9 telinit 

Copied from Super User.

Some user (I forgot the link. I believe it was in WSL's GitHub issues page, but can't find it) said it was systemd bug. It's fixed by now, but you need to upgrade systemd first.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --only-upgrade systemd
sudo apt upgrade

